# Not Able to Use Fout to Create and Name a file with a User Inputted Name

Tags: c++, file, stream, output, outputstream

I made a little program that gets the user to enter the name of a file, followed by the program creating a .doc file with that name.  Then, the user enters some input and it appears in the .doc file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   cout << "\nWhat do you want to name your file?\n\n";

   string name = "";

   char current = cin.get();

   while (current != '\n')
   {
      name += current;

      current = cin.get();
   }

   name += ".doc";

   ofstream fout(name);

   if (fout.fail())
   {
      cout << "\nFailed!\n";
   }

   cout << "Type something:\n\n";

   string user_input = "";

   char c = cin.get();

   while (c != '\n')
   {
      user_input += c;

      c = cin.get();
   }

   fout << user_input;

   cout << "\n\nCheck your file system.\n\n";
}
```

I'm receiving an error at the line where I create the file:

```
ofstream fout(name);
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.  `name` is a `string` var, which is the intended input for a `fout` object.

Comment: "I'm receiving an error" - what error? *Always* include the exact text of any errors you get in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass name.c_str(), ofstream does not have a constructor that takes a std::string, only char const *, and there is no automatic conversion from std::string to a char pointer;

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  It now makes sense to me why something like:  ofstream fout ("test");   works, because the string literal is converted to a c-string.  The same isn't the case with string vars.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to construct a `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` object from `std::string` was introduced only in C++11.

If your compiler has the option to compile against the C++11 standard, turn on that option. If you do that, you should be able to use

```
ofstream fout(name);
```

For example, if you are using `g++`, you can use the command line option `-std=c++11`.

If your compiler, does not support the C++11 standard, you will need to use

```
ofstream fout(name.c_str());
```